# QGIS cluster gdal Unknown option 'INTERPOL'

Tags: qgis, gdal, saga, linux-mint

I am running cluster analysis from image analysis menu of saga provider in QGIS.  I use the qgis GUI from processing tool box, I call saga modules.
I got same error in many other algorithms. I can read this lines:

Log pannel shows this message

> `io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS ....`
>
> *After other lines*
>
> `Unknown option 'INTERPOL'`

It seems to be that I am running wrong version fo qgis, gdal or saga in my system.

I am runnig

- Linux Mint 17.3 64 bits
- qgis 2.14.3
- saga gis 2.2.7
- gdal 1.11.2+dfsg-1~exp2~trusty

I made udate and upgrade in my system and got no difference.

Comment: Just to let you know my temporary solution to this problem: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14735#note-2

Answer (score 5):

I guess I found an ugly side of free software here.

One side, qgis programers really knows this problem since 10 months ago. They dicieded it is not their responsability to solve this problem and I found they are planning to **drop support to SAGA**.

The other side, SAGA is producing now more frequently new versions. Each new version with different name in parameters. It makes harder to link into qgis.

Normal user, like me, found that my updated system even with LTS (long term support) already found no support for the problem. The bug report is open now.

A month ago Max Bohnet presented [his solution to this problem](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14735)

But for my suprise, his message was marked as rejected because is a duplicate of [another report presented by Paolo Cavallini](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13279) 10 months ago.

Thanks to Bohnet, I found a folder in my system where are the versions of SAGA supported.

```
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/description
```

Now I have to consider to apply a downgrade of SAGA to keep connection in qgis.  I am planning to follow [instructions from howtogreek](http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/).

In consequence, I will drop some new algorithms and improvements of SAGA.  Another option I have is to write files like proposed by Bohnet and try to connect new SAGA versions to qgis.  At this time I have not time to do.

Comment: I think that there is an issue with SAGA GIS license since version 2.1 or 2.3, because thay are last versions included as OSGeo packages. SAGA GIS is a great development and we only can respect its licenses. By the way, If the question user account is yours, I think that you can merge your both accounts, also after losing access to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem and fixed it. There are a number of files other than the scripts (namely the description files) where INTERPOL shows up as a parameter, and it needs to be changed to RESAMPLING in those as well as the scripts. (See my answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217414/saga-algorithms-not-working-on-qgis-2-18-on-mac-osx/227659#227659).) I did my fix within the version 2.2.3 directory, but you can do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution based on Max Bohnet ideas.

In folder  `/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/description`

I found this folders

```
2.1.2
2.1.3
2.1.4
2.2.0
2.2.2
2.2.3
```

There is no documentation I found previously about this problem.  I supposed every code is a version of saga gis, then I created a new folder

```
2.2.7
```

Next, I **copied all the content** of 2.2.3 folder in  new 2.2.7

I did a copy of `/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/SagaAlgorithm214.py`  to `/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/SagaAlgorithm227.py`

Then I did edition of `SagaAlgorithm227.py`

```
Line 29 : from SagaAlgorithm214 import SagaAlgorithm214
Line 36 : class SagaAlgorithm224(SagaAlgorithm214):
Line 40 :         newone = SagaAlgorithm214(self.descriptionFile)
Line 64 :         return 'io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 --RESAMPLING 0 -GRIDS "' + destFilename + '" -FILES "' + source + '"'
```

I also edited file `/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/SagaAlgorithmProvider.py`

```
Line 54 :                          "2.2.7": ("2.2.7", SagaAlgorithm214)}
```

Now, **cluster analysis** is runing. I am not sure with the rest of the modules.

Final SagaAlgorithm and agaAlgorithmProvider editions are [in this folder](http://bit.ly/sagaCode).

Comment: I am afraid that Cluster Analysis is not working now.