# QGIS mac: Problem running several algorithms from toolbox

Tags: saga

**I want to use the SAGA algorithm "add coordinates to points", but I get an error message:**

> Algorithmus Add coordinates to points startet...
>   shapes_points "Add Coordinates to points" -INPUT "/var/folders/ls/7vyvyj2x0pg4yrw2gtqgpfs80000gn/T/processing0f42e6b113ae40f2bb6eae1dac046156/1480657898.143.shp" -OUTPUT "/Users/Hirschi/Documents/Uni/Module/GEO113/Uebungen/Lab8/Data/coord.shp"
>   /Users/Hirschi/.qgis2//processing/saga_batch_job.sh: line 3: 9194 Segmentation fault: 11 saga_cmd shapes_points "Add Coordinates to points" -INPUT "/var/folders/ls/7vyvyj2x0pg4yrw2gtqgpfs80000gn/T/processing0f42e6b113ae40f2bb6eae1dac046156/1480657898.143.shp" -OUTPUT "/Users/Hirschi/Documents/Uni/Module/GEO113/Uebungen/Lab8/Data/coord.shp"
>   Converting outputs
>   Lade Ergebnis Layer
>
> The following layers were not correctly generated.
>   Points with coordinates
>   You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm

**The log message window looked like this:**

> 2016-12-02T06:51:38   0   SAGA execution commands
>               shapes_points "Add Coordinates to points"  -INPUT "/var/folders/ls/7vyvyj2x0pg4yrw2gtqgpfs80000gn/T/processing0f42e6b113ae40f2bb6eae1dac046156/1480657898.143.shp" -OUTPUT "/Users/Hirschi/Documents/Uni/Module/GEO113/Uebungen/Lab8/Data/coord.shp"
>   2016-12-02T06:51:38 0   Konsolenausgabe der SAGA-Ausführung
>               /Users/Hirschi/.qgis2//processing/saga_batch_job.sh: line 3:  9194 Segmentation fault: 11  saga_cmd shapes_points "Add Coordinates to points" -INPUT "/var/folders/ls/7vyvyj2x0pg4yrw2gtqgpfs80000gn/T/processing0f42e6b113ae40f2bb6eae1dac046156/1480657898.143.shp" -OUTPUT "/Users/Hirschi/Documents/Uni/Module/GEO113/Uebungen/Lab8/Data/coord.shp"
>   2016-12-02T06:51:38 2   Error loading result layer:
>               Traceback (most recent call last):
>                 File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/gui/Postprocessing.py", line 75, in handleAlgorithmResults
>                   out.name))
>                 File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/dataobjects.py", line 199, in load
>                   + '\nCheck the processing framework log to look for errors')
>               RuntimeError: Could not load layer: /Users/Hirschi/Documents/Uni/Module/GEO113/Uebungen/Lab8/Data/coord.shp
>               Check the processing framework log to look for errors

Comment: Possibly related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217414/saga-algorithms-not-working-on-qgis-2-18-on-mac-osx